# Get unique data across certain column in multiple tables - sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this is probably so odd to ask. But lets say I have 3 tables:

Table 1

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam |
| 2 | David |
| 3 | Conor |

Table 2

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam |
| 2 | Derek |
| 3 | Niall |

Table 3

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam |
| 2 | David |
| 3 | John |

Is there any way I can write a query to get the unique names across all 3 tables. So it would return "Adam, David, Conor, Derek, Niall, John"

Order doesn't matter

If it helps, all name values are related to a `names` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes  , one way is to union them

```
select name from table1
union 
select name from table2
union 
select name from table3
```

union automatically removes duplicate cases

Comment: Thank you so much! Will accept the answer when I'm allowed

Comment: It says I can in 6 minutes

Comment: @Strawberry Lol I remember checking again and it said "You will be allowed accept in 1 minute" then I forgot..

Comment: @BranOIE Note that if a name is duplicated in the first table then this solution *still* only selects distinct names; I mention it only because it may seem counter-intuituve.